# Не загружать повторно контент в AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Я написал код, который "догружает" мне недостоющий контент при нажатии кнопки:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    let trigger = $('.left-side > div > a'),
        container = $('.right-side');

    trigger.click(function () {
        let $this = $(this),
            target = $this.data('target');

        trigger.removeClass('current-tab');
        $this.addClass('current-tab');

        container.load(target + '.txt');

        return false;
    });
});
```

При просмотре инспектора страницы заметил, что при нажатии на кнопки, мой код не смотрит на загруженные файлы на сайте, а продолжает подгружить по новой файлы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы мой код проверял на наличии "загруженного" на сайт файла и брал данные из него, вместо повторной загрузки файлов?

Comment: Складывайте загруженные файлы в словарь (где ключ - название файла, значение - содержимое). Перед загрузкой проверяйте вхождение ключа в словарь. Если есть - берём данные и словаря, нет - загружаем и заносим в словарь

Comment: @ArchDemon Можете привести пример кода или ссылку на ресурс, где я могу об этом узнать? Я JS знаю поверхностно